# How do I fix phpMyAdmin links issue

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have installed phpMyAdmin 5.2.0.

I have problem that menus, databases, tables totally all links didn't work. It seems links are not clickable. There is JavaScript issues in console too.

Is there any solution to fix this issue? I searched a lot.

[image]

error in console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Messages is not defined
    at new MenuResizer (menu_resizer.js?v=5.2.0:43:13)
    at HTMLUListElement.<anonymous> (menu_resizer.js?v=5.2.0:168:37)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js?v=5.2.0:2:3003)
    at obj.<computed>.each (jquery.min.js?v=5.2.0:2:1481)
    at obj.<computed>.init (menu_resizer.js?v=5.2.0:164:19)
    at $.fn.menuResizer (menu_resizer.js?v=5.2.0:203:27)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (functions.js?v=5.2.0:3619:17)
    at e (jquery.min.js?v=5.2.0:2:30038)
    at t (jquery.min.js?v=5.2.0:2:30340)
```

I installed phpmyadmin according below link:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-with-nginx-on-an-ubuntu-20-04-server

and upgrade by below link:
https://tecadmin.net/manually-upgrade-phpmyadmin-ubuntu/

I upgraded it because it had style issues.

Comment: Try to reinsall it clean and see if that helps

Comment: Also, if you upgraded it, maybe your browser cache hasn't reloaded so try clearing that too